# Wine installation problems in CentOS

Tags: centos, software-installation, wine

Every time I use...

```
yum install wine
```

I get a message saying the package isn't found. I have used `yum update` but that does not work either. Moreover I accidentally ran `chmod user:user /etc/yum`...

The system is 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 3rd-party repository named RPMForge which has a large number of packages which are not available officially from CentOS. [This page](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge) has instructions on how to install it on various CentOS releases.

About that `chmod` thing, can you reinstall **`yum`**. I'm not sure if it will help, but I expect that it will restore the directory to its initial permission settings.

Answer (score 0):

By deleting `/etc/yum` you deleted *all* configuration to yum, no wonder it doesn't work now. Luckily, the contents of that directory are part of the yum package (at least on Fedora, a close relative), so just reinstalling yum using rpm directly should fix this. Find out the exact version you have installed, and then do something like `rpm -Uhv --replacepkgs http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/yum-3.2.22-40.el5.centos.noarch.rpm` (this is for CentOS 5, look around in that site for your version if not 5). If this doesn't work, rummage around for updates in directories like `http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/updates/x86_64/RPMS/` for a file called similar to the above). Once that worked, do a `yum update --skip-broken` for good luck. A victory dance afterwards is optional. Going to the next wall and hitting the head *hard* isn't: It might help to remember that Linux does exactly as told, even if it doesn't make any sense. *You* are supposed to provide said sense.

**Do not** use `--force` on RPM, it tells it to go ahead even if dependecies aren't available, the result is a inconsistent system (that is very unlikely to work right). Don't ask when it should be used, it is a last-resort fallback for desperate situations. Like doing surgery with a swiss-army knife in the park.